# How do I use both cores on an RP2040 in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, embedded, rp2040

I have read that the RP2040 has two cores.  How can I use the second core in a Rust program?

I do not need to go all the way to generic multithreading, I just want to have two threads, each of which owns one of the cores, and they can communicate with each other.

The Rust book's section about Fearless Concurrency (suggested by Jeremy) is not much help.

```
thread::spawn(|| {
    let mut x = 0;
    x = x + 1;
});
```

fails to compile

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `thread`
   --> src/main.rs:108:5
    |
108 |     thread::spawn(|| {
    |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `thread`
```

which is hardly surprising given that `thread` is part of `std` and the RP2040 is a `#![no_std]` environment.

In the C API there is a function [`multicore_launch_core1`](https://raspberrypi.github.io/pico-sdk-doxygen/group__pico__multicore.html#ga46ea5e2efc181aba1d4d1de06a375c59).  Is there an equivalent Rust API?

Comment: You may want to read The Book's [Fearless Concurrency](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch16-00-concurrency.html) section, it has a good tutorial on how to use Rust's threads, including message passing. Chapter 20 has a more real-world example, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have already discovered, the multi threading facilities of the Rust `std` library rely on the facilities of an OS kernel which are not available when working in a bare metal embedded environment.

The actual process of getting the second core to execute code is a little complex and low level. It is described in the [RP2040 datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/rp2040-datasheet.pdf) in the section titled "2.8.2. Launching Code On Processor Core 1".

In summary - after the second core boots up, it goes into a sleep state waiting for instructions to be sent to it over the SIO FIFO, which is a communications channel between the two cores. The instructions sent through provides an interrupt vector table, a stack pointer and an entry point for the core to begin executing.

Luckily, the [rp2040_hal](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/) crate provides a higher level abstraction for this . The example below is from the [`multicore`](https://docs.rs/rp2040-hal/latest/rp2040_hal/multicore/index.html) module of this crate:

```rust
use rp2040_hal::{pac, gpio::Pins, sio::Sio, multicore::{Multicore, Stack}};

static mut CORE1_STACK: Stack<4096> = Stack::new();

fn core1_task() -> ! {
    loop {}
}

fn main() -> ! {
    let mut pac = pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut sio = Sio::new(pac.SIO);
    // Other init code above this line
    let mut mc = Multicore::new(&mut pac.PSM, &mut pac.PPB, &mut sio.fifo);
    let cores = mc.cores();
    let core1 = &mut cores[1];
    let _test = core1.spawn(unsafe { &mut CORE1_STACK.mem }, core1_task);
    // The rest of your application below this line
}
```

In the above example, the code within the `core1_task` function will be executed on the second core, while the first core continues to execute the `main` function. There are [more complete](https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal/blob/main/rp2040-hal/examples/multicore_fifo_blink.rs) examples in the crate's examples directory.

Disclaimer: I have not used this crate or microcontroller myself - all info was found from online documentation.

Comment: I had to bang on it with a rock a little bit, but eventually got my app working using both cores: one for real-time pin sampling, and the other for slow stuff like OLED, neopixels, and USB

Comment: @MutantBob I would love to see a code sample if you could share it, as I'm struggling with the same problem! Do you have a public repo, or could you share any portion of it? My email is tufelkinder@yahoo.com.

Comment: https://github.com/mutantbob/adafruit-macropad-rust/blob/0a23a4ab90a46650d244063cfc15948afc327eef/gaming-pad/src/main.rs#L115 , @tufelkinder